# Using tuple as argument for contract method

Tags: solidity, javascript, abi

I have a contract i would like to interact with and its abi method addProperties has the following listed:

```
addProperties: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  '0xa802047c': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
  'addProperties(string[],(uint256,string,bool)[],(string,string))':
```

how can i pass in with javascript a tuple containing uint256, string and boolean? in other words, how can i pass in that middle parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't have tuples, so you will need to present an array which can further be 'destructured'.

Looking at the docs:

> To pass a tuple in, you need to put in an array [].
>
> Similarly, to pass in a struct as a parameter of a function, it needs
> to be put in as an array []. Also note that the line pragma
> experimental ABIEncoderV2; needs to put in at the top of the solidity
> file.

Something like

```
myTuple = [{
   age: 907540,
   name: "myName",
   isAlive: true
}]
```

...could be passed as the second argument - as long as the function itself destructures it, you're good to go.